# Moore–Penrose Pseudoinverse of Squared Matrix Product

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

We want to show the following equation:
\begin{align}
\left(C'R'RC\right)^+=\frac{1}{T-1}\left(A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}\iota_N\iota_N'A^{-1}}{\iota_N'A^{-1}\iota_N}\right),
\end{align}
where $C=\left(I_N-\frac{1}{N}\iota_N\iota_N'\right)$, $A=\frac{1}{T-1}R'\left(I_T-\frac{1}{T}\iota_T\iota_T'\right)R$ and $I_N$ and $I_T$ are the identity matrices with dimension $N$ and $T$ respectively. $R\in\mathbb{R}^{T\times N}$. We know that the equation holds numerically and that $C$ is idempotent.

Comment: Any idea how to find a representation of the pseudo inverse is appreciated.

Comment: In fact, we are looking for the pseudo inverse of a square of a full rank factorization $A=RC$.